# How do specify an environment name for elastic bean stalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy to elastic beanstalk using the cli.

The command I run is

```
 eb create --modules ebtargets/goapi -v
```

I get the following error

```
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
INFO: Getting version label from git with git-describe
INFO: Uploading archive to s3 location: goapi/app-d4ec2-160630_135740.json
Uploading goapi/app-d4ec2-160630_135740.json to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Creating AppVersion app-d4ec2-160630_135740
--- Waiting for application versions to be pre-processed ---
Finished processing application version app-d4ec2-160630_135740
--- Creating modules ---
ERROR: ServiceError - ApplicationVersion app-d4ec2-160630_135740 must specify an environment name in env.yaml
```

I have the key `EnvironmentName` in my env.yaml file. Any help on this?

Comment: Did you end up getting this to work? I'm getting the same error but I'm assuming this is a bug in the Elastic Beanstalk CLI.

Comment: I could not get that to work. I think its a bug on their part.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I noticed you have to check your env.yaml into version control otherwise it won't be used:

```
git add env.yaml
git commit -m "add elastic beanstalk environment config"
```

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. The version control is something to do with `eb`? Or yours?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have an `.elasticbeanstalk` folder into your `ebtargets/goapi`

If necessary, use `eb init --modules ebtargets/goapi`.

More information [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebcli-compose.html)